# How to do arithmetic operations (+,-,/,*,%) inside a AWS cloud with the Data in a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, math, amazon-dynamodb, numerical-methods

Can some one help me and please let me know,Which tool in AWS I should use to perform math operations such as add/sub/mul/div/mod etc with data inside a dynamodb table? 
Currently I am hosting my data inside DynamoDB via raspberry Pi using python as my programming language. But with that raw data I need to do some computations. Initially,I  want to start with trying small computations.

So Which tool is helpful to do computations inside cloud such as doing some math and finding whether the number is even number or not ,giving some input and performing some algorithm and finding the result?
 I just want to pick data from my table residing in DynamoDB and do these computations.I saw Redshift in google but its little expensive,will it be possible to use that and load the data from dynamoDB to redshift and do the math operations or there any better alternate options?
Will you please share me any links that will help me to start with?

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

In DynamoDB, you can only increment and decrement numeric attributes using the + (plus) and - (minus) operators in the `SET` action of an `UpdateExpression` in [update_item](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item) or the `ADD` action if only both; the existing attribute is a number and the value is also a number.

Otherwise, you should perform your desired math operations against attribute values before updating them in DynamoDB.

**Note on** `ADD`:

> If you use `ADD` to increment or decrement a number value for an item
>   that doesn't exist before the update, DynamoDB uses 0 as the initial
>   value. Similarly, if you use `ADD` for an existing item to increment or
>   decrement an attribute value that doesn't exist before the update,
>   DynamoDB uses 0 as the initial value.

For example:

```
response = client.update_item(
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#C': 'Count'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val': {
            'N': '1'
        }
    },
    Key={
        'ItemId': {
            'S': 'BC3AB494-EDD8-4F47-B80F-32ACA92D8C5C'
        }
    },
    ReturnValues='ALL_NEW',
    TableName='MyTable',
    UpdateExpression='SET #C = #C - :val'
)

print(response)
```

See also: [Incrementing and Decrementing Numeric Attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement).

Comment: Hello ,Thank you very much for responding.But I want to do Math operations inside the cloud.Not just increment or decrement but some complex algorithm operations.Which includes all the calculations of the scientific calculator.So will it be possible to take the data that I was feeding into DynamoDB table and transfer to any other database or any other environment/tool and perform that operations and I want to display the processed data to users via  mobile apps xamarian But that is later part.Right now,Iterations like loops and do all math operations inside cloud?Please let me know.Thank you

Comment: Hello,I found the solution to solve this issue.We can use EMR,Spark,Hadoop tools from AWS.We can transfer our data from DynamoDB to S3 bucket as input and feed that Data To EMR and inside EMR we  can cluster and use SPARk/Hadoop to do the computations using any Programming languages we want and result can be retrieved back to S# buck as ouput and from there we can export data to DynamoDB table.

Comment: Check out this links http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark.html

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html

Comment: https://www.lynda.com/Hadoop-tutorials/Hadoop-Fundamentals/191942-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a20%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3aemr%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2